# How to write a custom action to install a UMDF driver?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, device-driver, umdf

I want to install a UMDF software, the only driver from our MSI, I understand that to do it, I need to create a root-enumerated device and then install the driver to driver store.
I have never written a custom action before.

Has anyone done it before and can get some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this topics in the [WiX Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/):

- [Extra Actions](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/extra-actions)
- [What's Not in the Book](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/events-and-actions/whats-not-in-the-book)

You may also want to read MSDN documentation on [Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368066.aspx).

Comment: @Navneet Gupta If an answer was useful to use, click Up arrow; if the answer solved your issue, click Accept. This way you give reward to people who help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to write your own custom action unless you have to because you will have to take care some complex things such as rolling back.

In this case, I would suggest you take a look at the Difx tool shipped with the WDK.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers ... I looked at Difx but looks like there are various limitations related to servicing and upgrades http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg35219.html